# Different prices for different day amounts on booking app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a site where you can book properties. The user should be able to enter different prices for different amounts of days. e.g. 1 day is 100€, but 2-4 days is 90€, but 5+ days is 80€.

Currently the app supports just one price. There is a `Post` model (the property) which has a
 `price` attribute.

I was thinking to maybe use a hash or array with the days and price amounts, but I am not sure how to implement it on the backend nor frontend.

Comment: I was also thinking to make a separate model, e.g. `PostPrice`, where it belogs to `Post`, and a `Post` can have many `PostPrice`s. And when making a `Post` to accept nested attributes for `PostPrice`s, which would have attributes like: `from_days`, `to_days`, `price` etc.

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, you will need another model. Just like you described in you comment above. In the form in the frontend you can have a repeater that adds a new line with the attributes you want, if you do not have a specific amount of entries. If you have a fix number of entries you can build the relation in the controller.